# check if a GWT MaterialCollapsible object is collapsed

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT MaterialCollapsible item in my java application. I thought that i could check if it's collapsed by using its methods isVisible() or isEnabled(), but they both return true all the time.

How do i get the collapsed state of this object?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me.
Let's say that we have a previously defined MaterialCollapsible widget, we can add a clickHandler to it, and inside the handler we manually set a boolean variable that keeps track of the current state of the widget:

```
//the widget
MaterialCollapsible collapsibleWidget;

//default collapsed
isWidgetCollapsed = false;

[...]

//this is necessary for GWT to handle the click, otherwise the handler won't be called
collapsibleWidget.sinkEvents( Event.ONCLICK );

//the handler
collapsibleWidget.addHandler( new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event ) {

           //save the widget state
            if ( isWidgetCollapsed == true )
                isWidgetCollapsed= false;
            else
                isWidgetCollapsed= true;


        }
 }, ClickEvent.getType() );
```

I hope you can find it useful.